# Оптимизация MySQL

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Мне нужно, чтобы на каждой странице сайта выводилось количество новых сообщений для пользователя (например, 30 новых сообщений). Для этого мне каждый раз из таблицы нужно будет извлекать `count(*)` количество сообщений для данного пользователя (а если в таблице всего тысяч 50 сообщений для всех пользователей, то это делать накладно). Как в этой ситуации поступить, может нужно кэшированием запроса воспользоваться?

Answer (score 2):

Т.к. сообщения лучше обновлять чаще раза в час, предлагаю сделать таблицу со спец.данными (сообщения, обновления другого рода) и обновлять ее при соответствующих действиях.

```
function addMessage($from, $to, $msg) {
  /* code */
  mysql_query('UPDATE upd_table SET total_in_messages=total_in_messages+1 WHERE userid='.$to.';');
  mysql_query('UPDATE upd_table SET total_out_messages=total_out_messages+1 WHERE userid='.$from.';');
  }
```

Там же можно сделать счетчик `new_messages_counter`, например.

Answer (score 1):

А можно сделать "ORDER BY `date_added` DESC LIMIT 30", не сильно затратно )

Answer (score 1):

count(*) - оптимизированная мускулем функция, и не тратится время на data transfer. так что действительно не сильно затратно.

Comment: Это если count(*) вызывается в таком виде:
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `aaa`, а если у меня ещё потом WHERE идёт, то я так понимаю, что ему полюбому нужно обращатся к столбцам

Comment: Время mysql  запроса делится на execution time, и data transfer time.
Если вы не вытаскиваете информацию из столбцов, то время будет маленькое, обращение к колонкам в конструкции where, сдесь не причем.

Для увеличения скорости можете добавить индекс для поля по которому фильтруете выборку (where.. )

Answer (score 1):

Немного разовью идею [[[[@Sh4dow](/users/465/sh4dow)](/users/465/sh4dow)](/users/465/sh4dow)](/users/465/sh4dow), создайте дополнительную таблицу с {userID, privateMessageCount} обновление privateMessageCount происходит через триггер на вставку в таблицу приватных сообщений пользователей записи о новом сообщении для данного пользователя (не стоит это делать через доп. запросы как это предлогает [[[[@Sh4dow](/users/465/sh4dow)](/users/465/sh4dow)](/users/465/sh4dow)](/users/465/sh4dow) - бессмысленная нагрузка для mysql, пусть и небольшая).

Да, и при необходимости получить count(*), просто получаем данные из описанной мною выше новоиспеченной таблицы.